# POST function not working with my php code however in the same function GET is working

Tags: php, html

```
<form class="form-inline" action="form.php">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
            </div><br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
            </div><br/><br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
            </form>




<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?><br/><br/>  : This is working.
<?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?><br/><br/> : this is not working.
```

shows error :Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\form.php on line 9

Comment: you can not have have post and get together for same form.

Comment: post the code of your form..if you are using get as method post wont work..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: does the field on your form called username have username spelled correctly? Hard to tell without the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the variable via the `$_POST` array, you have to specify `post` as the method in your form (or in whatever mechanism you're using to hit the file, like an AJAX request or something, you'd need to specify "post" accordingly):

```
<form method="post" action="your-file-or-route">
```

If you don't want to worry about that, or you don't care whether it got to you via POST or GET, PHP does offer a `$_REQUEST` array, which combines the two (and `$_COOKIE`).  See here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

(You may also want to check that the value exists in whatever array you use before you try to display it, with `isset()` [[1]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or `empty()` [[2]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or `array_key_exists()` [[3]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).)

Answer (score 0):

To use `$_POST[]` you have to set the `form method="post"` like:

```
<form method="post" action="">
...
</form>
```